# Why is /etc/lvm/archive or /etc/lvm/backup not readable by everyone

Tags: permissions, security, lvm

On a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ ls -l /etc/lvm
total 92
drwx------ 2 root root  4096 May 14 23:24 archive
drwx------ 2 root root  4096 May 14 23:24 backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 82910 May 12 15:29 lvm.conf
```

Why are the `/etc/lvm/archive` and `/etc/lvm/backup` directories not readable by everyone? Are there any specific security considerations with the exact lvm extent mapping being readable by everyone?

Comment: Disk and volume management are intrinsically admin operations, you don't want the average user to move your partitions and volumes.

Comment: @vfbsilva being to *read* LVM information doesn’t imply that you can move partitions and volumes.